# Prevent ESC from clearing text from <input type="search"> on Chrome (or add button to clear text without using type="search")

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I spent literally hours tracing down this issue in my code where `ESC` was clearing the input text only to find that it wasn't my code doing that. I found that `ESC` clears the text from `<input type="search" />`.

So when I found this, I thought all my problems were solved - only removing `type="search"` removes the button to clear the current text from the input. I figured I could restore this with a quick CSS rule, but it had no effect.

- `-webkit-appearance: searchfield;`

So next I tried preventing the action of `ESC` on the search field, but was unable to do this with:

- `evt.preventDefault()`
- `evt.stopPropagation()`
- `evt.stopImmediatePropagation()` -- technically the React equivalent `evt.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()`

How can I work around this issue without creating monstrosities in the DOM or in my code reinventing this built-in feature of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem. Turns out you need to:

1. listen for the `keydown` event
2. check that the `Escape` key was pressed
3. call `event.preventDefault()`

If you want to retain the default behavior of removing focus from the search field, you'll need to do that manually by calling `.blur()` on the search field. The snippet below assumes this is what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<p>Type into the search field and press the Escape key</p>

<input
  type="search"
  onkeydown="
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.blur();
    }
  "
/>
```

Of course, you don't have to use an inline handler. You can use something like `.addEventListener()` on the search field to do something equivalent, but since the asker mentioned they're using React, I assumed they'd prefer an inline solution they can apply via JSX. (You'll need to do the translation from HTML to JSX.)

This solution checks that `event.key === 'Escape'`, one of several ways to accomplish this. As of Jun 2022, the `KeyboardEvent.key` property is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=key). (If you need even wider support, there are [other properties on `KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) you can check like `charCode`, `keyCode`, `which`, etc, but realize several of them are deprecated and/or have caveats you'll need to handle.)

Answer (score 0):

You likely have to track the value and set the searchbox value to the last value when the esc key is pressed.

Something like this may work...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <input type="search" id="searchInput" />
    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        let searcText = "";
        const input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        input.onkeyup = (e) => {
            if(e.keyCode === 27) {
                input.value = searchText;
                return;
            }

            searchText = input.value;
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'd deem this to be one of the "monstrosity" approaches I aim to avoid. This is far more convoluted still to implement in React.

Comment: You're probably best off writing your own search component or getting one from npm instead of trying to bypass built in browser behavior